# create and return struct in declarative macro

Tags: rust, macros, metaprogramming

Back here with learning macros,

I'm wondering if a macro can generate a struct and return it.

I'm trying to iterate over multiple components in a ecs. I've managed to write the functions to iterate over one component type, and over all pairs of components, in a way that could be expanded to any number of component types.

So now, I want to make a macro that automate the process. The macro should :

- create a struct that will be the iterator, and that will be returned
- implement the Iterator trait on that struct
- build an instance of that struct and return it.

you can see [On the git page](https://github.com/VirgileHenry/Foundry/blob/main/src/ecs/component_table.rs) the implementations of the iterator, the structs, and the functions for 1 and 2 components, and they can be super easily extended (at the end of the file).

Here is what I'm trying for now :

```
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! iterate_over_component {
    ($ecs:expr; $($comp:ty),+) => {
        
        // create the result struct that will act as an iterator
        struct ComponentIterator<$($comp),+> {
            current_iterator: usize,
            current_entity: usize,
            $(
                array_$comp: Option<&'a Vec<IndexedElem<$comp>>>,
                current_index_$comp: usize,
            )*
        }
    };
}
```

But I'm having lots of issues :

- It doesn't seems the `ty` keyword accepts types ? I would like to call the macro like so : `iterate_over_component!(ecs; Position, Velocity)` (where Position and Velocity are structs types)
- I'm having errors when using the struct keyword at the beginning of the macro, so can I really declare structs in there ?

Comment: `array_$comp` won't work - not only can you use macros in the middle of identifiers like that, `$comp` is a type and not an identifier, and won't make a valid identifier name for something like `crate::components::Position<i32>`.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Shouldn't this juste result in like ```array_Position``` which is simply an field name ?

Comment: No. It would expand to two different tokens, `array_` and then `Position`, which won't parse. You'd need a crate like `paste` to combine them.